# window.onbeforeunload - Importing in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to use `window.onbeforeunload` in my project but I do not know how to use it.

I have tried in 2 ways:

**1st way**

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function(e) {
  return "Are you sure you want leave?";
});
```

**2nd way**

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  //   e.returnValue = "hello, are you sure???";
    return "You may lose the changes!!!\n are you sure???";
  //   return null;
  };
```

I get errors in both of them and I guess that it is because I did not import something, somewhere.

Furthermore, I would like to know if it is possible to redirect to an specific URL of my website when this event is called.

Example: Pressing F5 --> /dashboard/

Answer (score 1):

you have to import `@HostListener` and use it like below in your component

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) onBeforeUnload(event) {
           // do something here 
          console.log("method called");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a simple extra question. Could you answer it? Thank you. (I will mark your answer as correct in 8 minutes)

Comment: I don't approve of this solution : you **handle window logic in a defined component**, while your component should only hold logic on its own.

Comment: @trichetriche the point is OP was looking for HostListener and it's not necessary to be in the same component

Comment: No he doesn't look for `@HostListener`, he looks for a way to call `window.beforeunload`. HostListener happens to be one of the ways, but in this case, this is a very bad practice. And as I said, it is window logic, not a component logic, so this is why I don't approve of this solution. But as long as it suits his needs ... This was just my two cents !

Comment: How is this bad practice?  You create a separate component that handles window logic (call it WindowsLogicComponent), and use @HostListener.  This is much better than defining an asset JS file, modifying angular-cli.json, and not having access to any properties or injected angular services from within the asset JS file!

Answer (score 0):

create a file `beforeunload.js` that you put in the `assets` folder, containing

```
window.beforeunload = function() {
  // Do your stuff
}
```

In your `angualr-cli.json`, simply import the file :

```
"scripts": [
  "assets/beforeunload.js"
],
```

Comment: A quick note though : if you want to ask for confirmation before the user leaves one of your components (and not a confirmation on the whole page),  you should [take a look at this page](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes)

Comment: How could I jump to one specific route ? (/dashboard)

Comment: what if this is not required in some areas of the project? This looks global to me

Comment: That looks global because it is global. This is the window object, it is global by definition. If you want it to not be global, then you should use CanDeactivate, like I said in the first comment. And you don't redirect to another route of your  component, otherwise the user will never leave your page ! If you want to do that, you also need to use CanDeactivate.

Comment: I am trying to deploy a simple alert after pressing F5 but it seems that it does not work. I have created the file and I have edited my angular-cli.json. Should I do something else?

Comment: Is the file imported in your project ? (if not, you should see an error) what happens when you close the tab, is it triggered ?