# Restrict refreshing the page |Browser Restriction | angular 6 |

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, angular6, angular-route-guards

I am using angular 6 for my project, I need to restrict the user from refreshing the page.

- when the user tries to click on the refresh button of the browser or press ctrl+f5 etc, I would like to restrict the user and show the page for it.

> show alert message if he is refreshing the page

Comment: Can you please show what you tried to accomplish so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser Restriction | angular 6 | restrict back navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294840/browser-restriction-angular-6-restrict-back-navigation)

Comment: @briosheje -  When user clicks on refresh button i want to show an alert message

Comment: you need to listed to `window.onbeforeunload` event and show the alert message

Comment: @Niladri - in angular 6?

Comment: @Hitesh yes you can do it in Angular 6 also .. check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834775/window-onbeforeunload-importing-in-angular2/47834828#47834828