# Angular's LifeCycle Hook ngOnDestroy not working on mobile

Tags: angular

I have this piece of code in my Angular app that works correctly on desktop. But, for some reason on the phone, it's not working.

I am testing this on google chrome app on an iPhone. I can't seem to find any documentation on whether or not chrome app supports ngOnDestroy. Here is my code:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.chatService.leaveChat('User left');
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  doSomething() {
    this.ngOnDestroy();
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should work if the component is destroyed. Are you sure your component gets destroyed on mobile view or simply hidden? The `beforeunload` event is fired when the window, the document and its resources are about to be unloaded. The document is still visible in that case why will `ngOnDestroy` be called?.

Comment: The only time in both mobile or desktop the component is destroyed is when; the user refreshes the page or closes the tab. In both cases unfortunately for mobile the component is never destroyed. Or at least the method never triggers.

Comment: Maybe it is just being hidden like you said? I'm not sure? I didn't know that's how mobile google chrome works. I would think mobile chrome would work similar to desktop chrome.. not sure

Comment: On refresh or when you navigate away from the current page, then `ngOnDestroy` won't be called. The application will just be destroyed by the browser.

Only when Angular removes the component from the DOM because you move away or you call destroy() on a dynamically created component, then `ngOnDestroy()` is called.

Comment: you should be doing `window.onbeforeunload = () => {
            //call your method from service
        };` in stead of adding a HostListener, may be host is always present

Comment: Or check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47834828/9386929

Answer (score -1):

`ngOnDestroy` is a lifecycle hook that is not meant to be triggered manually. It runs when component gets destroyed. It doesn't have to do anything with the browser.

You might want to wrap everything that exists in the `ngOnDestroy` in an other function and call that function in both `ngOnDestroy` and on `window.beforeunload`.

e.g.

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy()
  }

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  onDestroy() {
    this.chatService.leaveChat('User left');
  }
```

Comment: I will try this... now i'm having problems with my ec2 instance so I can't checkout the solution atm.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix my problem.